# std::scoped_lock - vector of mutexes?

Tags: c++

How can I apply a `std::scoped_lock` on a `std::vector<std::mutex>`? I've tried:

```cpp
std::vector<std::mutex> mutexes;

std::scoped_lock lock{ mutexes };    // doesn't work
std::scoped_lock lock{ ...mutexes }; // doesn't work
```

Comment: I don't see a way that will be possible. `scoped_lock` accepts mutexes as a variadic list, but `vector` is a runtime sized container whereas variadic lists are a compile-time construct, so these designs seem fundamentally incompatible.

Comment: Your next best option may be an accompanying `std::vector<std::lock_guard<std::mutex>>` that pair element-wise with your `mutexes` container. Although (as I'm sure you're aware) when juggling multiple mutexes at once be wary of the [dining philosophers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem) in terms of lock/unlock order.

Comment: @PKramer I am outputting data from multiple sources, so I must lock each source's mutex so that the source's data I am iterating over is not modified. They must all be locked at the same time as the data is time sensitive and outputting takes some time.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question, I now see what you want to do. scoped_mutex only accepts a variadic parameter pack and there is no way to convert a vector (runtime structure) to a parameter pack (compile time structure).

Comment: @user16850544 This is not a client synchronization problem then, you basically need a shared reader/writer lock on all producers. And thus a way to create one and inject it into the producers.

Comment: Since the number of threads is not fixed, can't you keep one single mutex at the side that is reading from the sources instead? Don't let them write while you are reading. Otherwise, [here's a (probably error prone) version to lock a vector of mutexes](https://godbolt.org/z/3W6xcdso8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global mutex shared between the output function and sources was the best solution.